# variable isn't getting saved

Tags: javascript, recursion, return-value

I'm trying to solve a problem by using recursion. The objective is to take an input string sentence, and return a new sentence, where each word's first letters have been deleted until the first letter of each word is a vowel.

Here's my attempt:

```
function deleteConsonants(sentence) {
    let words = sentence.split(" ");
    let newWords = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let newWord = shifter(words[i]);
        newWords.push(newWord);
    }
    return newWords.join(" ");
}

function shifter(word) {
    let vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    let wordArr = word.split("")
    if (!vowels.includes(wordArr[0])) {
        wordArr.shift()
        newWordArr = wordArr.join("")
        shifter(newWordArr)
    }
    return word
}

// let a = deleteConsonants("I love pizza") // "I ove izza"
// let b = deleteConsonants("This is blasphemy sir") // "is is asphemy ir"

// console.log(a)
// console.log(b)
```

I ran Chrome's debugger and it seems like the function "shifter" is working properly until it reaches the step where it returns a word. My variable "newWord", the one that gets pushed to the new array, for some reason ends up being the old, not changed version of the word.

Comment: Should be `return shifter(newWordArr)`

Comment: I tried this in replit just now, but it gives me the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Then you put it at the wrong place, I only added the return statement, put the return just before the recursive call.

Comment: @luk2302 wants you to put the return here;
        "return shifter(newWordArr)" ~Line 19 
I just replicated it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function deleteConsonants(sentence) {
    let words = sentence.split(" ");
    let newWords = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let newWord = shifter(words[i]);
        newWords.push(newWord);
    }
    return newWords.join(" ");
}

function shifter(word) {
    let vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    let wordArr = word.split("")
    if (!vowels.includes(wordArr[0])) {
        wordArr.shift()
        newWordArr = wordArr.join("")
        return shifter(newWordArr)
    }
  return word
}
```

You'd get the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error if you remove the return outside the `if` block. You need both of them